# An error occurred while installing curb (0.8.5)

Tags: ruby, linux, bundler, curb

While bundling an old project, this error came up:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/dd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/dd/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
    --with-curl-dir
    --without-curl-dir
    --with-curl-include
    --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
    --with-curl-lib
    --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/
    --with-curllib
    --without-curllib
extconf.rb:18:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in /home/dd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/curb-0.8.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/dd/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/curb-0.8.5/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing curb (0.8.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install curb -v '0.8.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: A fix for OSX Mountain Lion would be huge. This one finally made me make the switch to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I found the solution [here](http://taimoorchangaizpucitian.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/feedzirra-installation-problem-faced-solution-how-i-installed-feedzirra/)

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3-dev
```

Comment: This worked but only after running `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 11):

On CentOS

`sudo yum install libcurl-devel`

Answer (score 4):

It says it can't install [curb](https://rubygems.org/gems/curb) gem. Go to curb homepage and check [installation section](https://github.com/taf2/curb#installation):

> On Ubuntu, the dependencies can be satisfied by installing the
>   following packages:
>
> $ sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev
>
> On RedHat:
>
> $ sudo yum install ruby-devel libcurl-devel openssl-devel

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```